# Probability density of average of uniform two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to compute the probability density for the random variable
$$
\hat{Y} = \frac{1}{2} (\hat{X}_{1} + \hat{X}_{2}),
$$
where $\hat{X}_{1}$ and $\hat{X}_{2}$ are independent and are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.
I know that if we write $\omega \in \Omega$, $\hat{Y}(\omega) = \delta(y-y_{0})$ for any  $\omega \in \Omega$, then
$$
\langle \hat{Y} \rangle = \int_{0}^{1} \delta(y-y_{0}) p(y) \,\textrm{d} y = p(y_{0}) .
$$
Using the result, then
$$
p(y_{0}) = \langle \hat{Y} \rangle = \left\langle \delta \left[ \frac{1}{2} (x_{1} + x_{2}) - y \right] \right\rangle .
$$
Might I use this to figure out the probability density of $\hat{Y}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are $\hat{X_1}$ and $\hat{X_2}$ independent?  If so then Let $U=$ sum and $f_U(u)=\int\limits_0^1 I_{(0,1)}(x-u)dx$  So $f_U(u)=u$ for $0\le u \le 1$ and $f_U(u)=1-u$ for $1\le u \le 2$.
$\hat{Y}=\frac{U}{2}$ with $f_{\hat{Y}}=4y$ for $0\le y\le 0.5$ and $=4(1-y)$ for $0.5\le y\le 1$..

Comment: To underline the importance of the independence question: Suppose $X_1\sim U(0,1)$. Then choosing $X_2=1-X_1$ still has $X_2\sim U(0,1)$ but now $Y=\frac12(X_1+X_2)=\frac12$.

Comment: Yes, $\hat{X}_{1}$ and $\hat{X}_{2}$ are independent. Thank you for pointing that out. Could you explain what the notation $I_{(0,1)} (x-u)$ means?

Comment: $I_W(x)=1$ for $x\in W$ and $=0$ otherwise.  The expression for$f_U(u)$ is the usual way (convolution) to get the distribution of the sum of independent random variables.

Comment: Can $I_{W}(x-u)$ be related to $\delta(x-u)$ in anyway?

Comment: In a non-rigorous way Let $f(x)=I_{(0,1)}(x)$ then $f'(x)=\delta(x)-\delta(x-1)$.

Comment: Personally I try to avoid using delta functions.